# Is there a name for the "3d" version of a crescent shape?

Tags: shapes

Is there a name for the "3d" version of a crescent shape, like there for square (cube), circle (cylinder) etc.  Can I call it a "crescent prism" - is this a valid term for it?

[image: 3d-crescent]

Comment: Croissant. Mmmm.

Answer (score 3):

This shape is unlikely to be common enough to warrant a single word to uniquely describe it.  The mathematical term for the crescent shape formed by two circles is "lune" (Source [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_%28mathematics%29) ).  So "Extruded lune" or "Extruded crescent" would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You imply that the 3D version of a circle is a cylinder, but that is not the ONLY 3D shape possible (sphere, etc.).

However, based on your image, the shape you are describing is called an

> [extruded crescent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrusion)

(An extruded circle would also be a cylinder as you described).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrusion